# Best way to develop a php open source application

Tags: web-development, development-process

I started to create a php application I'd like to make open source in the near future. However I do not know, if it's needed to follow any kind of code/documentation convention, to make it more usable and acceptable when released.

Is there any model, to follow, to develop a good open source application?

Do you think it is necessary(or better) to develop it entirely, or for the most, object oriented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for a commonly accepted, worldwide used standard?

For PHP, there is none. There is [PSR](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md), but I won't say it's *commonly accepted*.

This being said, depending on the place you want to publish your application to, there may be some hints about the preferred convention. You may look at some already published projects and see what are the standards they follow.